# How to avoid <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">?

Tags: vb.net, json, web-services, serialization

I have built a very simple web service using the VB.NET "WCF Rest Service Application" project template (Is this a good choice?). I works well except the fact that there is

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
...
</string>
```

added to my answer.

I have declared my return value as a String :

```
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="member/login", Method:="POST",
            responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Public Function Create(data As IO.Stream) As String

        Dim strData As String = New IO.StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd()
        Dim UserAccessForm As LoginAccess = Me.getAnswer(strData)
        Dim jsonAnswer As String
        jsonAnswer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserAccessForm, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)
        Return jsonAnswer
End Function
```

So instead of having as answer this :

```
{"logged":false,"userID":"0","message":"Empty body"}
```

I get :

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
{"logged":false,"userID":"0","message":"Empty body"}
</string>
```

**Is there any way I can avoid this unwanted serialization of my string answer?**

Comment: Probably the above is all ready answered before. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8344219/1093668

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem and solved it by applying the `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute to the service contract.

Here's a c# snippet - hope it helps you.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
interface IHuggies
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/CheckIfConsumerExists")]
    bool CheckIfConsumerExists(string parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work, note the `Stream` as return argument.

```
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="member/login", Method:="POST",
            responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Public Function Create(data As IO.Stream) As Stream

        Dim strData As String = New IO.StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd()
        Dim UserAccessForm As LoginAccess = Me.getAnswer(strData)
        Dim jsonAnswer As String
        jsonAnswer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserAccessForm, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)
        Return New  MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonAnswer));
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (responseformat.Json being the magic word):

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/json")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string json()
    {
        return "{\"test\":\"ok\"}";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of reading on this and it looks like XML is the standard response in C#.  I ended up with this:

```
    private void MakeCall()
    {
         RestClient rc = new RestClient();
         ...
         var jsonData = returnJson( rc.MakeRequest());
         ...
    }

    private string returnJson(string response)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(response);
        return doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.InnerText;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public String cleanOUTPUT(String OUTPUT) {
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replaceAll("<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">","");
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replaceAll("</string>", "");    
return OUTPUT;
}
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, showing what it does and how it solves the problem. This will help others in the future