# Cant serialize respose from oauth RESTful webservice - Error in XML Doc(1,2)

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I've been looking for an answr for this for hours now and the more i read the more confused i seem to get! Basically as the question implies, i'm trying to serialise a response from my web service but cant convert the xml back to an object

First off my web service has this class object

```
[Serializable()]
    [XmlRootAttribute("WcfRESTful")]
    public class testcc
    {

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("field1")]
        public string f1 { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("field2")]
        public string f2 { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("field3")]
        public string f3 { get; set; }


        public testcc() { }

        public testcc(string _f1, string _f2, string _f3)
        {
            f1 = _f1;
            f2 = _f2;
            f3 = _f3;
        }
}
```

To serialize the data on the web service side i do the following

```
public string GetTest_With_OAuth(string username)
        {
            if (Authenticate(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest))
            {
                try
                {

                    //Serialize emp in the xmlTextWriter
                    List<testcc> emplist = new List<testcc>();
                    testcc emp = new testcc("Hello","Some", "Person");    
                    string XmlizedString = StringSerialize(emp);
                    return XmlizedString;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errHandler err = new errHandler();
                    err.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Invalid User
            }
        }

private string StringSerialize(testcc data)
        {
            TextWriter w = WriterSerialize(data);
            string xml = w.ToString();
            w.Close();
            return xml;
        }

        private TextWriter WriterSerialize(testcc data)
        {
            TextWriter w = new StringWriter();
            this.s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WcfRESTful.testcc));
            s.Serialize(w, data);
            w.Flush();
            return w;
        }
```

So basically it returns me back the following data as a string which i then attempt to serialize

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <WcfRESTful xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <field1>Hello</field1> <field2>Some</field2> <field3>Person</field3> </WcfRESTful></string>
```

This is the code i use to deserialize

```
public testcc DeserializeString(string xml)
        {
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            return Deserialize(reader);
        }

public testcc Deserialize(TextReader reader)
        {
            testcc o = (testcc)s.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return o;
        }
```

Everytime though it is failing on `testcc o = (testcc)s.Deserialize(reader);`with There is an error in XML document (1, 2) and i cant seem to figure it out but it is basically the last thing i need to do for my webservice id=f anyone has any input i'd appreciate it. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the  tags or even how to remove them :/

***Edit***

On the client side i'm parsing the webresponse as follows

```
serilizer serializer = new serilizer();
                try
                {
                    string xml = string.Empty;
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    testcc item = serializer.DeserializeString(xml);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
```

I have a breakpoint at `testcc item = serializer.DeserializeString(xml);` where i am having a look at the `string xml` variable

Comment: Where does the `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">` come from? If your serialized stream is as you have written then it's malformed XML since the `<?xml ...>` should be at the start of the XML document.

Comment: I still don't know where that `<string>` node is coming from. Using your code I can serialize/deserialize your class without a problem, but the serialized string doesn't contain that `<string>` node.

Comment: Please take a look at this question on [how to avoid it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216260/how-to-avoid-string-xmlns-http-schemas-microsoft-com-2003-10-serialization). It might come from the webservice and using the proper attributes for the methods might suppress that.

Comment: I found that question as well and made the change as specified, now that string line appears as : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <WcfRESTful xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <field1>Hello</field1> <field2>Some</field2> <field3>Person</field3> </WcfRESTful></string>

Comment: so bascially its added another xml declaration...