# How to remove the outerXML from WCF service response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, serialization

I need to build a WCF Service. I did it successfully. It gives me following output result.

**Result output:**

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
   <AmountResponse>
      <Status>-8</Status>
      <ErrorCode>-8</ErrorCode>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
   </AmountResponse>
</string>
```

This service will use by a financial organization. They request to change the result little bit.

**Need to remove** `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">` and `</string>`

I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216260/how-to-avoid-string-xmlns-http-schemas-microsoft-com-2003-10-serialization/14994256#14994256) and add `[XmlSerializerFormat]` to my interface. After doing that result shows as:

```
<string>
   <AmountResponse>
      <Status>-8</Status>
      <ErrorCode>-8</ErrorCode>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
   </AmountResponse>
</string>
```

From this result I want to remove `<string>` and `</string>` so that it will look like as:

```
<AmountResponse>
   <Status>-8</Status>
   <ErrorCode>-8</ErrorCode>
   <Amount>0</Amount>
</AmountResponse>
```

**Is there any way that I can remove `<string>` and `</string>`?**

Comment: What have you tried, and where exactly are you having trouble? How is the data available now (as a `string` object, as and `XmlDocument`, other)?

Comment: Show us the service's contract (the interface that the service implements)

Comment: show us the contract and your AmoutResponse class declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream Form();
```

...

```
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public Stream Form()
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = 
               "text/html";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A working class hero is something to be "));
    }
```

...