# WCF FaultException<string> namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk

I am having a problem regarding namespace returning from WCF service when there is a fault.As a part of removing BizTalk based WCF services, I am trying to build an exact replica of the same service using vanilla C# WCF.

In BizTalk based service fault message contains namespace `'xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'` in `<Detail>` section. But is my C# WCF services fault messages it missing this namespace

BizTalk Service Fault Message

```
       <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <s:Header />
        <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:ValidationError</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value>s:ItineraryNameInvalid</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-AU">'Itinerary Name 'EEE' is invalid.'</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
         <s:Detail>
            <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">'Itinerary Name 'EEE' is invalid.'</string>
         </s:Detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But in C# based WCF service namespace for the "`<Detail><string missing namespace?>`" is missing.

C# WCF fault message

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <s:Header />
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:ValidationError</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value>s:ItineraryNameInvalid</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-AU">'Itinerary Name 'EEEE' is invalid.'</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
         <s:Detail>
            <string>'Itinerary Name 'EEEE' is invalid.'</string>
         </s:Detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Code

```
catch (ValidateException ex)  {

                     string messsage = ex.Message;

                     var fcs = new  FaultCode(ex.FaultSubCode);
                     var fc = new FaultCode(ex.FaultCode,fcs);
                     var fr = new FaultReason(messsage);

                     throw new FaultException<string>(messsage, fr, fc);
                 }
```

Any clues or thoughts to add this missing namespace would be most appreciated?

Comment: Opposite of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216260/how-to-avoid-string-xmlns-http-schemas-microsoft-com-2003-10-serialization     It looks like you have to have the string be read by a StreamReader