# JSON starts with XML <string> [{…}] </string> How can I access the JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, xml, wordpress, api

I am creating some custom pages on wordpress and so far so good but I am still new to php development, but I am using an external API.
The API gives out  its  data as JSON wrapped in a XML string like
`<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{..JSON..}</string>`
I am hoping someone can help me understand how I  can  access the JSON within the XML String so I can display the data? Thank you in advance

Comment: If the question isn't about using a XML/DOM API first, and doing the JSON extraction in step 2, then what is it?

Comment: Is the API configuring the output to be JSON? (The XML you give is not correct anyway as the end tag `</string>` doesn't match any start tag).

Comment: A little confusing from the API to wrap json in xml, but it seems you have to deal with the xml first in order to get to the json. See: https://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Refering to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343553/restful-web-service-returning-xml-not-json/8344219#8344219 id check are you requesting with the correct headers first. Assuming that the api is an .net service then its quite picky on how you request it.

Comment: @NigelRen Honestly i am not to sure how it is being configured. Its an API I want to use not what I have built. I accidentally missed the start <string....> when writing the question.

Comment: @OlliTyynelä  Thank you - I do believe its a .net service, so this may prove useful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you call the remote endpoint from PHP and receive a string response as you describe, *and* you are not interested in any XML part, then a couple of lines can extract the json string part.

```
$data = '<xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><string>{"a":10, "b":"Hello World"}</string>';
// If the above looks like the data you receive, then:
    
$start = strpos($data, '<string>{');
$end = strpos($data, '}</string');
$json_str = substr($data, $start+8, $end-$start-7);

$json_array = json_decode($json_str, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your target json is hiding inside an xml snippet, you have two basic alternatives to handle it.

First, you can try using string manipulation methods to extract the json out of the xml snippet. For that, I would use:

```
$string = <<<XML
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{..JSON..}</string>
XML;

$json_str = explode("<string>", $string);
echo $json_str[0];
```

The output, using the xml in your question, is

```
{..JSON..}
```

A more complex way to handle it, but one which I believe is safer, is to treat xml as xml and use xpath on it. Using that approach:

```
$my_xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$results = $my_xml->xpath('//*[local-name()="string"]');
echo $results[0];
```

Same output.